# Selecting duplicate points on a list of data

Tags: select, duplicates, union, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to drop some elements of a list of data in Mathematica, but I don't understand how `Select` and `Union` work. For example, suppose I have the following list

```
list = {{0.10,0.20},{1.10,0.20},{0.70,0.80},{0.20,1.10},
    {1.20,1.20},{0.12,0.18},{0.68,0.76}}
```

and only want elements in `(0,1)x(0,1)` considering that points within a distance radius of `0.05` are duplicates. In the example,

```
list1 ={{0.10,0.20},{0.70,0.80}}
```

I don't care which element represents the equivalence class. I'm doing the following:

```
list1 = Select[list, 0 < Part[#,1] <1 &];Select[list,0 < Part[#,2] <1 &]
```

which gives the points in `(0,1)x(0,1)`, but if I try to use `Union`, such as

```
Union[list1, SameTest -> (Abs[#1-#2] < 0.05 &)]
```

I get slot errors.

Can someone explain to me how to do it neatly?

---EDIT---

Using

```
DeleteDuplicates[list1, Abs[Part[#1, 1] - Part[#2, 1]] < 10^-6 &]
```

does the trick, but I wonder why I can't work with a list of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of approaching this. One way to do it, that I think is the neatest, since you require your elements to be in certain intervals, is to use `IntervalMemberQ` with `Select`.

For example, to narrow down your list to those points in `(0,1)x(0,1)`:

```
list01 = Select[list, And @@ IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, 1}], #] &]

Out[1]= {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.8}, {0.12, 0.18}, {0.68, 0.76}}
```

Secondly, to eliminate duplicates, use `DeleteDuplicates`, which is the perfect tool for this task. You can use the same test using `IntervalMemberQ`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list01, 
 And @@ IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, 0.5}], Abs[#1 - #2]] &]

Out[2]= {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.8}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the problem. What I don't understand is why in this case there are no slot errors, wich is the reason I use Part.

Comment: @Manuel `DeleteDuplicates` checks all pairs of elements, each "element" here being a sublist of `list01`. The slot `#1` refers to the first of the pair and `#2` refers to the second.

Comment: I like it. But sometimes is deceiving. Try for example `list01 = Union[Tuples[{1, 0}, 2], {{1/2, 1/2}}]`. It returns {0,0}, but {1,1} is outside its equivalence range.

Comment: @belisarius I see what you're saying, but from my understanding of the problem, `{1,1}` should be in the result. If you have `{{0,0},{1/2,1/2},{1,1}}`, according to the OP, either `{{0,0},{1,1}}`  or `{{1/2,1/2}}` are acceptable answers. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Both `{{0,0},{1,1}}` and `{{1/2,1/2}}` are acceptable, as I don't care for the equivalence class representative, because the interval of _equivalence_ I'm using is very small, but in an abstract situation this problem should be addressed.